# Access class property declared in constructor

Tags: typescript

I have the following class:

```js
export class CommandHandler {
  constructor(private readonly commands: Collection<string, BotCommand>) {}

  public static async load(loggingEnabled?: boolean): Promise<CommandHandler> {
    ...
    return new CommandHandler(commands);
```

I would like to access the collection in another file, here I call the class and initialize it in my index like

```js
(async () => {
  await createConnection();

  const client = new Client();

  client.once('ready', () => console.log(`${client.user.username} is online.`));

  const handler = await CommandHandler.load(true);
```

How can I access the collection in another file?

```js
import { CommandHandler } from '../../CommandHandler';

// I would like to access the collection here
```

Comment: Do you want to get the static method load in another file?

Comment: No in my index file I do const handler = await CommandHandler.load(true); so there I have access to the class and it's methods, I can create a method to return this.commands but if I want to access the class in another file I would have to call the load method first to get a instance of the class but I don't want to load() everytime I want to access the class properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a service for sharing your data between different classes for more information you can
[read this](https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/services).

```
export class CommandHandlerService {
    //Properties which you want enabled from another classes
      someProperty;
   //

   public loadData(){
        // you can execute some method here

       // you can assign some values to the local properties
       this.someProperty = 'instance or new value';
   }
   // declare a get accessor for each property which want to get for example
   get property() {
       return this.someProperty;
   }
}
```

Inject it in the index class for init properties

```
constructor(
    private commandService: CommandHandlerService,
) {
    CommandHandlerService.loadData(); //load all service properties
}
```

Inject it in the class constructor where you want to get the data from command service.

```
     constructor(
    private commandService: CommandHandlerService,
) {
    let variable = CommandHandlerService.property //access to the service property
}
```

I hope I've helped you.